# Ignore fields only in json but not xml with jackson-dataformat-xml

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-serialization, jackson-modules

Using `Jackson` with the `jackson-dataformat-xml` module, I am able to serialize `POJO` to both `JSON` and `XML`.  There are a few fields (xml attributes) in my object that should only be serialized to `XML` but not `JSON`.  If I apply the `@JsonIgnore` annotation, the field is completely ignored even with `@JsonXMLProperty`.

How can I ignore fields only in `JSON` but not `XML`?

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Mix-in](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations) feature. For example, assume that your `POJO` class looks like this:

```
class Pojo {

    private long id;
    private String xmlOnlyProperty;

    // getters, setters
}
```

Now, you can define annotations for each property using `Mix-in` interfaces. For `JSON` it looks like below:

```
interface PojoJsonMixIn {

    @JsonIgnore
    String getXmlOnlyProperty();
}
```

For `XML` it looks like below:

```
interface PojoXmlMixIn {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    String getXmlOnlyProperty();
}
```

Finally, example how to use `Mix-in` feature:

```
Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
pojo.setId(12);
pojo.setXmlOnlyProperty("XML attribute");

System.out.println("JSON");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixInAnnotations(Pojo.class, PojoJsonMixIn.class);
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(pojo));

System.out.println("XML");
ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
xmlMapper.addMixInAnnotations(Pojo.class, PojoXmlMixIn.class);
System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(pojo));
```

Above program prints:

```
JSON
{
  "id" : 12
}
XML
<Pojo xmlns="" xmlOnlyProperty="XML attribute"><id>12</id></Pojo>
```

Comment: Is there any annotation to ignore only in XML?

Comment: @Thirumal, no but you can use `MixIn`.